# chrome.scripting.executeScript takes too long to start at document_start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Building a sample Chrome extension, its sole purpose is to wrap/replace `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

It was easy with `Manifest V2`, but seems to be tricky with `Manifest V3`.

The replacement is achieved using `chrome.scripting.executeScript`, which is triggered immediately from a `document_start` content script, which sends a message to the `background` worker, which in turn uses `chrome.scripting.executeScript` on the calling tab.

The whole thing takes from `500ms` to `1500ms`, which usually misses many initial `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest` requests, which is unacceptable for my use case - I need to control all requests.

Is it possible to delay scripts on the original tab until the replacement is finished? Am I doing something wrong here? Any other solution to guarantee a replacement before requests are made?

(using `https://www.msnbc.com/` in this example, but tried many other websites)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "v3ChangeFetchExample",
  "description": "v3ChangeFetchExample",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "scripting"],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["script.js"],
      "matches": ["https://www.msnbc.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.msnbc.com/*"]
}
```

background.js:

```
const replaceFetch = async function (message) {
  fetch = {};
  XMLHttpRequest = {};
  console.error(`Took ${Date.now() - message}ms`);
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    world: "MAIN",
    target: { tabId: sender.tab.id, allFrames: true },
    func: replaceFetch,
    args: [message],
  });

  sendResponse(true);
});
```

script.js:

```
(function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(Date.now());
})();
```

Edit: Just found this in the documentation of `chrome.scripting.executeScript`:

> Injects a script into a target context. The script will be run at
> document_idle.

This sheds some light on the issue. So maybe the question should be: Is it possible to execute a script on `document_start`, and not `document_idle` using `Manifest V3`?

Comment: Not possible, see https://crbug.com/1217895. Extensions like yours are currently completely broken in MV3. In the future you will use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts to register a main-world script at document_start.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. What do you mean when you say in the future? I see in the docs that RegisteredContentScript is available starting from Chrome 96 and the public version is 98. Also seems like it has a run_at property that can be document_start, so I must be missing something else.

Comment: It doesn't support `world` yet.

Comment: @wOxxOm, how would your answer change now? The issue was just closed as fixed with this remark: This should be fixed and available for use in M102.

Comment: It's simpler to use inline js in an attribute as shown in [method 3 here](/a/9517879). It'll work on this site because its CSP doesn't forbid inline js.